# Can you give me a example of dependency injection without frameworks?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I want to reduce the coupling between two components, then I thought of `dependency injection`, but for a long time, I just use `Spring` to implement this. But now, I am working in a project which is not suitable to use this framwork(it is too heavy).

So can you give me an example to implement `dependency injection` for myself?

Answer (score 2):

[Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is a pattern that can easily used without framework support. Some even prefer it without framework support, but at least, whether or not a framework is actually beneficial depends on the [way you use such framework](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/) and the type and size of application you are building/maintaining.

Dependency injection is simply about injecting the dependencies into a component from the outside. The most common and advised way to do so is through constructor injection. This means that a class should specify all its dependencies as constructor arguments.

You should always design your code as if there is no DI framework at all; your application code should be oblivious to the existence of such framework. This means that you should never decorate your code with framework specific attributes. They pollute your code and cause a vendor lock-in. If the DI library you use requires the use of attributes, switch to a different library.

The use of dependency injection will 'bubble' throughout the application. This means that a class that applies the dependency injection pattern will move the responsibility of the creation of its dependencies up the call stack. This means that the consumer of that class now becomes responsible of creating its dependencies. But since that consumer should apply dependency injection as well, it means that it pushes the responsibility of creating the dependencies up again. When all classes apply the dependency injection pattern, it means that the complete object graph(s) need to be created in a single place in the application. This is actually a good thing. This place is called the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Again, you don't need to use a DI library (a.k.a. IoC container), and your application code should definitely not depend on it. You should apply the Dependency Injection pattern (and the SOLID principles) to make your application maintainable. A DI library can be used to make your composition root maintainable, but it should ONLY be used IF it makes the composition root more maintainable. Not using a DI library gives you complete compile-time support over the creation of your object graphs. Using a DI library will make you lose this compile-time support, so the advantages of its use should outweigh the disadvantage of losing compile-time support. Furthermore, you need to make sure that you can verify the building of your object graphs during application start-up or at least in a test suite. If your DI container makes this hard to impossible, switching your library or building your object graphs by hand might be a better option.

Comment: "Using a DI library will make you lose this compile-time support" is not really valid now with the advent of Dagger 2

Comment: @GauravVashisth A link to an article that describes this would be helpful.

Comment: Here are some http://google.github.io/dagger/ https://blog.gouline.net/2015/05/04/dagger-2-even-sharper-less-square/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? Java has excellent CDI framework. Its lightweight and easy to use. For more info, see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhl.html

Comment: If Spring is too heavy, than a JEE container is likely to be too heavy as well